# Как пишется "cупер-премиум-класс?"

Tags: орфография, словообразование, дефис, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Речь идёт о кормах для животных. У них есть деление по качеству на эконом, премиум и т. д. Самые лучшие корма — супер-премиум. Но вот я не знаю, как правильно писать: "супер-премиум-класс" или "супер-премиум класс"? С одной стороны, "супер-премиум" — это определение класса корма, поэтому дефис вроде бы не ставится, а с другой — рука так и тянется его поставить.)))
А как всё-таки правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае наименование категории качества не стало русскими словами. Например, "супер-" употребляется как приставка (сверх-) в заимствованных словах, а как отдельное слово встречается только в качестве междометия (Супер!); с дефисом тоже трудно представить себе правильно образованное слово (обычно слитно). Это транслитерация (перенос по буквам и их сочетаниям), которую для распознания названия в тексте нужно писать в кавычках. Дефис при таких переносах из другого языка (в английском они пишутся раздельно) появляется лишь в некоторых случаях (напр. в географических названиях: Лос-Анджелес). Поэтому логично употребить без дефиса и в кавычках: **класса "супер премиум"** (более формально - можно оставить название в латинице, тогда без кавычек: класса Super Premium). Сложнее со случаем, когда хочется употребить всё это как эпитет - по аналогии с выражением "**экстра-класса**" (нужен дефис в другом месте). В этом случае вряд ли можно к выражению в кавычках приделать внешний дефис. Здесь уже потребуется словообразование, и видимо, такое: корм **суперпремиум-класса**. Без кавычек, поскольку имеет место уход от названия класса (это уже эпитет с намёком на него), и слитное написание приставки "супер-", как это принято в других словах (супермаркет, суперзвезда).

Answer (score 2):

С написанием слов подобного рода пока определённости нет. Словари не успевают фиксировать неологизмы, широким потоком хлынувшие в наш язык.
Приставка супер- в русском языке пишется слитно. При слиянии её со словом ПРЕМИУМ образуется определение слову КЛАСС. Ср.: класс (какой?) суперпремиум. Поэтому писать нужно ***суперпремиум класс.*** (но: суперкласс).

Comment: В русском языке нет слова "суперпремиум", даже со скидкой на "временное отсутствие определенности". Для аналогичного слова "экстра" время неопределённостей прошло, но самостоятельным русским словом оно не стало. Недопустимо употреблять такое слово как прилагательное (а перед существительным оно становится таковым), как в предложенной записи. Формальное "супер премиум" (с русским родовым понятием в начале) остаётся транслитерацией, как бы его ни трактовали рекламщики, а в случае сохранения английского порядка слов его ждёт та же судьба, что и "экстра-" (суперпремиум-класс, компакт-диск и т.п.)

Comment: С ЭКСТРА тоже что-то непонятное происходит. В словаре Б.З. Букчиной и Л.П.Калуцкой "Слитно или раздельно?"  (М., "Русский язык", 1988), стр.843) все слова с приставкой ЭКСТРА- пишутся слитно, в слове ЭКСТРАКЛАСС в том числе.

Comment: Нашлось слово "премиум-класс" (через дефис) в орф. словаре Лопатина ("суперпремиум-класс" напрашивается по аналогии). Более старое слово с аналогичным написанием: бизнес-класс. А вот экономкласс пишут вместе и объясняют это тем, что слово можно рассматривать как сложносокращённое (от "экономный/экономический" и "класс"). С "экстрой" - непонятная история, но хорошо хоть, что отдельно не предлагают его написать (пока были только одноимённые марки соли и спирта).

Answer (score 1):

1. Я полагаю, что в ответе Alex_ander был дан верный вариант: ***суперпремиум-класс.***

Формант-приставка «супер» относит к слову "премиум" и поэтому пишется с ним слитно, а все сочетание надо писать через дефис по образцу «премиум-класс».

2. Но вот **Грамота.ру дает нам свой ответ.**

Вопрос № 295224. Как правильно: супер-премиум-класс или «суперпремиум-класс?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Верно написание с двумя дефисами: ***супер-премиум-класс.***

3. Логика понятная (по образцу: мини-компьютер и супер-мини-компьютер), но чисто формальная. Слово ***«супер-премиум-класс»*** напоминает мне длинный товарный поезд, как и многие подобные слова с двумя дефисами – **некрасивая графика, размытое значение**. Да и произносится слово явно с двумя (а не тремя) ударениями, основным и вспомогательным.
4. Но – правило, как его обойти!  Если слово пишется через дефис, то приложение в препозиции тоже должно писаться через дефис. Так, кажется? И все-таки к подобным словам нужен индивидуальный подход и точная фиксация в орфографическом словаре.  Такой подход представляется более ответственным, чем мнение справочной службы.

**Примечание.** Пользователям тоже не нравится  запись с двумя дефисами, и они предпочитают писать приложение после определяемого слова, например: **корма эконом, премиум и суперпремиум** https://blitzpet.ru/article/klassifikatsiya-suhih-kormov/
А если поставить приложение перед  определяемым существительным, то получится:  эконом-корм, премиум-корм и суперпремиум-корм. Это вполне ясное и правильное решение для этой **конкретной темы**. В других же случаях пишут как кому нравится, безо всякой системы.